# Python Threading problems

Tags: python, multithreading

Im trying to understand threading (im new to it) to get my code better. For now, i have a class in a .py file with some functions.

In my main, i initialize an object for this class in each program i have. But, with threads, i would like to be able to create all this objects in one program and call the function with thread.

```
def inicializa():
clientList = list()
thread_list = list()
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("accounts.ini")
for section in config.sections(): #define a section da conta que vou usar
                    email = config.get(section,'email')
                    password = config.get(section,'password')
                    the_hash = config.get(section,'hash')
                    authdata = config.get(section,'authdata')
                    authdata = eval(authdata)
                    client = MyClient(email,password,the_hash,authdata)
                    clientList.append(client)


for client in clientList:
    t = threading.Thread(target=client.getBla()) # this function is inside of my class, its work OK outside of the thread if i put client.getBla.
    thread_list.append(t)

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.start()

return clientList
```

the error i get when i try to use the thread to start the function client.getBla is:

Exception in thread Thread-1:
 TypeError: int object is not callable.

My function dosnt take any arguments, so i don't know whats going on, because i client.getBla() outside of the threads works ok.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

```
t = threading.Thread(target=client.getBla())
```

What this line does is evaluate `client.getBla()` (which returns a `int`) and pass it as a named argument to the Thread. The `target` argument takes a callable, so you should do this instead:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=client.getBla)
```

Doing this, you pass the function itself, not the *function result*

Comment: Wow, that was a pretty fast answer, i think it's worked. Like i said, thats my first time with threads, is there any way to check if the threads are working simultaneouslyand not like a "for" ?

Comment: @JeffersonNeves a foolproof way of doing that would be to block the thread, using, for example, `time.sleep()`. If you perform sleeps of 1 second in 5 different threads, the program should finish in 1 second, not 5.

Comment: not sure where to use the time.sleep() but i will try it. I will post the result soon. Thank you.

Comment: Hey goncalo, 

In my code, i have some functions that the output is an input for another function. Example: bla = getBla(arg1,arg2,arg3) and then getPlof (bla, arg2, arg3) how can i use this in thread format?

Comment: @JeffersonNeves just define a new function that has a `bla` local variable and calls `getBla` and `getPlof` in sequence, and run that function in the thread